# Where is the cut off on marketing questions?

Tags: discussion

[Is the use of a QR code worth the space it requires?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57209/are-qr-codes-a-good-idea)

To be clear I like the above question as a question. I'm just not sure its a good fit for our website.

Other topics in the [marketing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) tag appear more design focused to me:

- [How much text should I use for an ad image?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55795/how-much-text-should-i-use-for-an-ad-image)
- [Using real products when creating fake mockups](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37331/using-real-products-when-creating-fake-mockups)

The above two seem okay to me. The QR one, to me, has nothing to do with design though. It's not asking about how to put a QR code onto a design, how to design around a QR code, or anything really design oriented. Its basically asking what the benefits of a QR code is. I think that's a fundamental difference.

I like Scott's QR question, I'm just not sure its a good fit for our site. Where do we draw the line on Marketing questions?

I do hope others might join me in following [Area51: Marketing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75798/marketing)

Answer (score 4):

I can see your point. However consider this....

The QR question is related to the display of information and how that information is conveyed to a reader. Is that not design?

While it certainly skirts the line between marketing and design, the question as I see it, leans more towards design because I'm asking about the use of information in visual terms. If I were to ask how to track QR data, collect scan rates, utilize data in a web site, etc then it would be more on the marketing side.

It's no different than asking *"Should I use all cap type for a headline?"* While yes, there is some marketing impact, the core of the question is about the visuals, not the data return and I think *that* makes the difference.

Comment: This here is the right way to look at it.

Answer (score 3):

I do think it is an okay question, but just in this case. I do agree that not every *'is XXX a good idea'* question should stay here.

QR codes, however, are a commonly recurring issue in design and marketing. Designers tend to hate them, clients tend to love them. There's lots of discussion about this issue in Designer-land. Hence, I do think this a useful question to stay, even if it's an exception to the rules I'd like to see enforced.

Comment: What is the "common issue" though and how does Scott's question address it?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I like marketing, but I also like structure. **I think the QR question needs to be closed.** It has nothing to do with design in its current form. Just adding on, "..in design?" doesn't make it a design question.

This would be an example of a Design Barcode question:

[Design Considerations for a custom UPC code](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51888/design-considerations-for-a-custom-upc-code)

There is no mistake that it is a design question.

I just don't see that in the aforementioned Marketing Question. If it were asking how large a QR code should be, how to seamlessly integrate it into a design, anything design related, then I'd say leave it. But right now I think it should be closed until it can be reworded at least.